# hide tabpanel in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, tabpanel

Guys. I have a question of how to hide tabpanel in R shiny.
I read a reference here. 
https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.5/showTab.html

Then, I revised my code based on this reference, but it didn't work. 
Here is a part of my code:

```
  ui <- fluidPage(

sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.tabselected == 1",
    ....
   actionButton("hideTab","Hide Tab"),
   actionButton("showTab","Show Tab")
  ),

  mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                tabPanel(title = "D", 
                         value=1),
                tabPanel(title = "S", 
                         value=3),
                tabPanel(title = "Y", 
                         value=2),
                id = "tabselected")
  )
```

...

```
      server <- function(input, output) {
  hideTab(inputId = "tabselected", target = "Y")
})
```

}

Is there anything to do with the conditionPanel? or there might be other reasons? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The `value` provided to hideTab is wrong:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.tabselected == 1",
        actionButton("hideTab","Hide Tab"),
        actionButton("showTab","Show Tab")
      )
    ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel(title = "D", 
                             value=1),
                    tabPanel(title = "S", 
                             value=3),
                    tabPanel(title = "Y", 
                             value=2),
                    id = "tabselected")
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$hideTab, {
    hideTab(inputId = "tabselected", target = "2")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```